Even if "Backface Culling" is not checked, the mesh will still be incomplete
Just like the gif shows. Even when I disable shaders, some meshes still don't show up. But those meshes definitely exist when I check in Edit Mode. The normal direction is correct, and Backface Culling is disabled.

Download .blend from OneDrive

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

it looks like it has to do with your armature settings, disable the Armature modifier and your mesh will look good

@moonboots,Thank you. After disabling the armature, the problem was indeed resolved. The model was imported through an immature plugin, but I really didn't expect any mesh visual display related issues to arise due to the armature.

don't forget to upvote moonb's comment so he gets credit for his time and talent.

@james_t thanks, I can't find why the armature deforms the mesh though

It has to do with your armature settings, disable the Armature modifier and your mesh will look good.
